# C# GUI save input text (TextBox)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-interface, textbox

I'm pretty new to the C# and while making my first program i'm facing a problem.

So I got 3 windows form  `(MyForm1; MyForm2 and MyForm3)`

`MyForm1` has 2 buttons (Available Account & Add a new account)
When i click one of these buttons it opens a new windows form.

In the Add a new Account form I have `2 TextBox` (1 for the ID and 1 for the PWD + Button (Save) and i'd like the user to input his ID and PWD and save it so i can re-use it in the Available Account form but i have no clue how to that.  I tried different things i saw on YT but nothing seems to works like i would

Thanks for your help <3 (Tell me if you want me to copy/paste some part of the code).

**Edit:**

Here are the sourcecodes of the mentioned forms.

- [Form1](http://pastebin.com/XMSrhgGS)
- [Form2](http://pastebin.com/43e9fcwE)
- [Form3](http://pastebin.com/gKb0pytW)

I deleted all my failed attemps, so they are basics.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far.@Jonathan Niixtay

Comment: For that you have to use Database that will store the values ie username and password.

Comment: And... please explain in more detail where your actual problem is.

Comment: @Pirate dont think he meant "save" to keep it outside of application cycle. I more believe he just wants to "pass" the Information from one form to another and he doesnt know how. so a temporary "save"

Comment: if he want to save the data that will available after the application close then he need to use database or file handling.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is devoid of any useful information, and will likely be closed until you add that information.

Answer (score 1):

From your post it's hard to determine what you're trying to do. So. If you only want to pass values between forms, you could do something like this:

Add new account form:

```
public static bool AddNewAccount(out int id, out string password)
{
    id = 0;
    password = "";

    AddNewAccountForm f = new AddNewAccountForm();
    bool result = (f.ShowModal() == ModalResult.OK);

    if(result)
    {
       id = f.GetId();
       password = f.GetPassword();
    }

    f.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

and in main form:

```
int id;
string pass;

if(AddNewAccountForm.AddNewAccount(out id, out pass))
{
   //here user clicked OK, so you can save to the database your id and password
}
else
{
   //here user clicked Cancel
}
```

I assumed that there are two buttons on your AddNewAccountForm. One - OK and the other - Cancel. You have to set the modal result for these buttons.

So, how it works?
AddNewAccount method is static method, so you can call it from your main like:

```
AddNewAccountForm.AddNewAccount()
```

AddNewAccount method is going to create your form, show it modally and then assign values enetred by user to out parameters.

My code assumes also that your AddAccountForm has methods like:

```
int GetId()
{
   return Convert.ToInt32(idTextBox.Text);
} 

string GetPassword()
{
   return passwordTextBox.Text;
}
```

Note that GetId is badly written, I wanted it to be clear. Now that you understand this method, conversion to int should look like that (TryParse is better way to convert string to int):

```
int GetId()
{
    int id;
    if(!int.TryParse(idTextBox.Text, out id))
      return -1;
    else
      return id;
}
```

You can also "group" id and password in some structure. Code would be cleaner. But I don't think you need it now. However, if you are curious you can read about structures here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you want to store values in database or files:

** **Part about good practices and system engeneering** **

You should really not save them using AddAccountForm. This class is to create account in your application (just the model) - not to save it. If you want to store these values(id and password) you should pass them to your main form - as I already showed you and then main form should save them - using another class which is responsible for data management. I am not giving any example, because I don't know if you really need it now.

Comment: Would it be possible to talk in something like facebook ? (I'm not an annoying personn i swear) So i could send you pictures of what the GUI looks like i think you'll instantly understand what i have in mind

Comment: Write me an email. It would be simpler for me. I will answer within 2 days: ajachocki (at) gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

To make your code really reusable, you should keep a strict separation between display (view) and the data.

You didn't mention that you had a database. This lack of mention is a start of this separation. Your problem would be similar if you just have a List of account, or a Dictionary, or maybe a text file containing the items you want to edit in your application.

So let's assume you want to edit a collection of `Accounts`. You want to be able to add an Account to this collection, or change the data of an existing account in this collection.

This functionality is similar to the functionality of an `ICollection<Account>`.

So all that `Form1` needs to know, is that it holds an `ICollection<Account>`. Somehow during initialization `Form1` loads the Accounts collection. If the operator presses Add, a `Form2` opens where he can fill in the required values for a new Account. The operator chooses either `OK` or `Cancel` to indicate he want this Account to be added to the collection or not (Using a Save button in the form is not windows standard and a bit unclear, so don't use it).

**Add an Account**

Code in `Form1`

```
private ICollection<Account> existingAccounts;

void OnButtonAdd(object sender, ...)
{
    using (var form = new Form2())
    {
         form. ...// fill any needed values

         // show form2 and check if OK or Cancel:
         var dlgResult = form.ShowDialog(this);

         // only add if OK pressed, otherwise ignore
         if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             this.existingAccounts.Add(form.Account);
         }
    }
}
```

Cond in `Form2`

In visual studio designer create a Form with a TextBox for the ID and a textbox for the password (give it password properties, so it displays *****)

Add an OK and a Cancel button. Give the DialogResult property of these buttons the proper OK and Cancel value.

Finally add one property to get the typed values:

```
public Account Account
{
    get
    {   // extract the values from the display
        return new Account()
        {
            Id = this.TextBoxId.Text,
            Pwd = this.TextBoxPwd.Text,
        };
     }
 }
```

**Edit existing Account**

You also have a button to edit an existing account. Do you only want to edit the last Added account, or do you want to be able to edit any existing account?

In the latter case you'll have to make something that displays all existing account where operators can select one of them. Probably using a DataGridView, or a BindingSource. You'll probably end up with a function like:

```
Account GetSelectedAccount() {...}
```

The Form to edit an existing Account is similar to the form to create a new account. You should really consider using the same form for it.

```
public Account Account
{
    get
    {   // extract the values from the display
        return new Account()
        {
            Id = this.TextBoxId.Text,
            Pwd = this.TextBoxPwd.Text,
        };
     }
     set
     {
         this.TextBoxId.Text = value.Id;
         this.TextBoxPwd.Text = value.Pwd;
     }
 }
```

In form1, upon pressing Edit:

```
void OnButtonEdit_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    using (var form = new FormEdit())
    {
        Account accountToEdit = this.GetSelectedAccount();
        form.Account = accountToEdit;
        // or: GetLastAddedAccount if you only want to edit the last added one

        var dlgResult = form.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {   // extract the edited Account from the form:
            Account editedData = form.Account;
            this.UpdateSelectedAccount(editedData);
        }
    }
}
```

Like in the examples above I usually decide to have an interface with a property that inserts and extracts Accounts instead of accessing every Account property separately. This allows you to change internals of an Account without having to change all (software) users of this Account

Comment: I feel bad you shouldve take a lot of time to write this and i still don't know how to use it :/  I tried but nothing seems to work, i'm obviously doing it wrong + i'm not sure that is the right code for what i am trying to do. 

Here images of the GUI (should be easier to understand what's on my mind) :
[Form1](https://pasteboard.co/GEQFjev.png)
[Form2](https://pasteboard.co/GEQG0Fp.png)
[Form3](https://pasteboard.co/GEQGaiQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about passing data between forms, So you can use one of following :

- set the user input in public string so you can access the strings from other forms by the input form object.
- you can pass the user input as constructor parameters and then use the data in your form.
- there are also other multiple ways like **delegate** but i think the 2 previous ways are simple.

Comment: Meh, thanks for trying to help but i don't really understand :/  I thought my project was pretty simple but i might was a bit too ambitious.

The idea was to make a program that store multiple League of Legends accounts so i can switch accounts faster than typing and without having to remember all of them. 

So Form1 to ask if i want to connect to an available one or create one. If available one pick an Account (and it start League of Legends with the account selected) or create one enter ID & PWD (in TextBox) then it would be added in the available acc form as a list

Comment: in your input form :
- create public string to save data into
- then when you try to open other form, pass this string